# Using jQuery deferred to submit form only if a series of processes pass

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, form-submit

Firstly, I admit that getting a hold over deferred pipe API has been the most challenging things to me recently.

**Requirement**

I would like to submit a form if a series of checks pass.

- Some of them would be functions with synchronous client side validations and some would be asynchronous checks which do an AJAX call. The asynchronous functions return a boolean callback value.
- Both the synchronous and async functions may have `confirm()` prompts to take user input. The user input will decide whether the next block will execute or not (if user opts cancel for a confirm dialog, next block should not proceed) and hence the form should not get submitted. *This is very important.*
- The form should only be submitted if all the individual blocks return (or callback) true.

*Added later*
- The asynchronous functions may contain the ajax calls inside some conditions, hence in some use cases, the ajax call may not be done.

- Inside the asynchronous functions, there could be user confirmation check inside the AJAX response handling code.

**Following are the structures of my functions -**

```
function synchronousMethod()
{
  //some logic
  return (confirm("user input"));
}

function aSynchronousMethod1(callback)
{

   if(condition)
   {
        //ajax call
        callback(bool); //does callback true/false
   }
   else
   {//some use cases may follow this path and not make the AJAX call at all. 
        return true;
   }
}
```

**Following is one of my trials with $.Deferred (may be I am doing it completely wrong)-**

```
$.when( synchronousMethod(), aSynchronousMethod1(),aSynchronousMethod2())
.done(function() {
    //I want to submit my form if all the functions returned/called-back true
    console.log("submitting form");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
});
```

But the text "submitting form" executes before the completion of the asynchronous function and the anychronous functions also cause this error `TypeError: callback is not a function`.

I observed that none of the functions execute if I don't put the brackets after the function calls inside the `$.when`, i.e. if I keep it like this -

`$.when( synchronousMethod, aSynchronousMethod1,aSynchronousMethod2)`
But none of the functions execute.

**Update**

*Another approach*

I also tried something like this, but had similar issues as with the first approach -

```
var promise = defer.pipe(synchronousMethod);
promise = promise.pipe(aSynchronousMethod1); 
promise = promise.pipe(aSynchronousMethod2);
promise = promise.pipe($("form#frmCampaigns").submit());
```

**Update 2**
Added two more points -

- The asynchronous functions may contain the ajax calls inside some conditions, hence in some use cases, the ajax call may not be done.
- Inside the asynchronous functions, there could be user confirmation check inside the AJAX response handling code.

Updated structure of asynchronous function -

```
function aSynchronousMethod1(callback)
{
        //some sync logic here
    if(condition) /*some condition*/
    {
        //ajax call
        if(ajax sucess response)
        {
             callback((confirm("If user accepts"));
        }
        else
        {
        callback(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {//some use cases may follow this path and not make the AJAX call at all. 
        callback(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sandeepan, I'm curious as to why you're using $.deferred for form validation? If you're using jQuery, why not just use normal $.post and render the next block in the event of a success callback?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completly understand your example. But I think the problem might be, that your asynchronous methods should return a Promise (like the return value of $.ajax):

```
function sync() {
    return "something";
}

function async1() {
    return $.ajax("http://www.foo.com");
}

function async2() {
    return $.ajax("http://www.bar.com");
}

$.when(sync(), async1(), async2()).done(function() {
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CcsQz/

**Update**

Ok, I see. Maybe you can do something like this in your case:

```
function syncOrAsync(sync, confirm) {

    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred()

    if (sync) {
        deferred.resolve();
    } else {
        $.ajax('http://www.foo.com').done(function(data) {
            if (confirm(data)) {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            deferred.reject();
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise();
}

var confirm = function(data) {
    // check confirmation here

    return true;
}

var method1 = syncOrAsync(true, confirm);
var method2 = syncOrAsync(false, confirm);

$.when(method1, method2).done(function() {
    console.log('done');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mKdwN/

Comment: thanks for the answer. But my situation is a bit more complicated. Please check the *Update 2* section in my question.